# Poincare polynomials for Borel Moore homology and fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, geometric-representation-theory

For an algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we denote $H_k(X)$ as its Borel-Moore homology of degree $k$. Let us define the Poincare polynomial associated it by
$$P(X)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}dim H_k(X)q^k$$
**My question is**:

If we give a fibration $F\hookrightarrow X\rightarrow Y$ which is local trivial for the Zariski topology,
I wonder if we have $P(X)=P(Y)\cdot P(F)$

**Motivation**: Since the virtual Poincare polynomials have this good property. But the virtual Poincare polynomials are equal to Poincare polynomials only if $X$ is smooth and complete. Hence, I guess we will get this good property if we change cohomology of a variety by its Borel Moore homology.